# Unable to install or run rospy

Tags: python, installation, rospy, drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've just installed the latest drcsim. From what I've read, a way to use python scripts is included in the ros package it comes with, rospy.

However, when I try to use rospy, the terminal does not recognize the command, when I searched for it with which rospy, nothing came up.

For some reason, rospy is not be included in the drcsim package, how do I go about installing it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3652/unable-to-install-or-run-rospy/) by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 34 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-07-19**:
Hi, have you sourced the needed files?
you have to source the drcsim setup.sh
`source /usr/share/drcsim/setup.sh` in every terminal
if this does not source the ros files you might have to source them manually too.
`source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash`

if you are using this frequently you should at the source command to your .bashrc files

**Comment by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on 2013-07-20**:
Files were already sourced in the .bashrc files, this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Issue has been resolved. Apparently, latest modifications has changed rospy to rospython, so I can use that to launch my script.

---

Originally posted by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) with karma: 34 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0